# How to sort a sharepoint list according to average rating column in react js?

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts, sharepoint-framework, reactjs

I have  a list which is to be sorted accoring to the average rating column and the top 3 items is to be displayed in react js.

This is the api endpoint used :

```
${this.props.siteurl}/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Site%20Pages')/items
```

How to sort the result according to the average rating column to get the 3 top rated items ?

Answer (score 2):

The average rating of a column is stored in a list column whose internal name is `AverageRating`. However, to sort on that column we need to make a POST request with a CAML query as it can't be `ordered by` in a normal `HTTP GET` request.

Make the changes from the below sample code in your `spHttpClient`'s methods :

```
const options: ISPHttpClientOptions = {
    headers: {'odata-version':'3.0'},
    body: `{'query': {
      '__metadata': {'type': 'SP.CamlQuery'},
      'ViewXml': '<View>
                    <Query>
                      <OrderBy><FieldRef Name="AverageRating"" Ascending=""False"" /></OrderBy>
                    </Query>
                    <RowLimit>3</RowLimit>
                  </View>'
    }}`
  };

var endPoint = `${this.props.siteurl}/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Site Pages')/GetItems`;

this.props.spHttpClient.post(endPoint,
    SPHttpClient.configurations.v1,
    options)
    .then((response: SPHttpClientResponse) => {
      console.log(response.json());
      return response.json();
  });
```

Comment: hey @swetanayak, hope this answers your question. Please mark it as answer if it helped your query, its just a checkmark besides the answer ! It will remove this from the unanswered section as well. Thanks !